# How to ignore part of JSON data if its image URL is broken

Tags: http, get

I'm working on a project which requests data from an API. Suppose I'm getting a list of actors data (with image URL) in one HTTP request. Some of the actors' image URL is broken and not available. This situation makes my project a bit disordered.

Is there any way to skip the actors whose image is unavailable and access all other actors' data whose image is available?

A sample code will be appreciated

Comment: Is `getting a list of actors` one http request or multiple http requests? Does the actor response data includes his/her image url, and you use this url to fetch the image? What do you mean by `access all those particular requests`?

Comment: Yes. It's a single http get response where the actor's name and image URLs are in JSON format. Yes, I use the URL to fetch the image. And by access all those particular requests, I mean, the JSON data of particular actor's name whose image URL is not broken in a list of array of JSON actor details.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions for your issue.

1. Once an actor's image URL is broken, use a default image as its `src`. The code would like: `<img src="actorX.jpg" onerror="this.src='defaultActor.jpg'">`.
2. Once an actor's image URL is broken, hide the whole actor content. The code would like: `<img onerror="window.hideErrorActor(this)" src="actorX.jpg">`. A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/4cb16yhc/) is made for example. Please check it if you need.

The key for these 2 solutions is `onerror` event handler of `img` element. When image load fails (e.g. URL broken), `img` element will fire an `error` event, and the function registered to `onerror` attribute will run. Inside the function, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: This works fine. How can it be implemented when I'm using ng-repeat in angularJS for the image URLs from JSON data ?

Comment: If you use `ng-repeat` in AngularJS to render the actors content, you can give each actor block an `id` (either from JSON data, or from `$index`), and manipulate corresponding `id` block when `onerror` happens.

Comment: @9094US is your problem solved? If yes, maybe you can "accept" this answer?